# Uploading a file to a directory outside of RAILS ROOT with attachment_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment-fu

I'm trying to use attachment_fu to upload files to a directory outside of the `RAILS_ROOT`. I want the files to be saved to `~/APP_NAME/uploads/` so that they can be approved/rejected before becoming publicly available. I've tried the following configuration for `has_attachment`:

```
has_attachment  :storage => :file_system,
                :path_prefix => "~/APP_NAME/uploads/",
                :max_size => 5.megabytes
```

Unfortunately, this configuration simply creates the `~/APP_NAME/uploads/` directory structure in `RAILS_ROOT`. Any way to save the file outside of `RAILS_ROOT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative method that suits me better than using relative pathnames. I added a method called `full_filename` to my attachment class:

```
class attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    def full_filename
       return  "/Users/ron/attachments/#{id}.#{file_format}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't an Attachment-Fu issue, but rather how Ruby handles File I/O as well as how files are stored in Unix.

So for instance if your app lives in, say, ~/Users/ron/APP_NAME

If you change the above code:

```
:path_prefix => "~/APP_NAME/uploads/"
```

To:

```
:path_prefix => "../#{RAILS_ROOT}/uploads"
```

The files would be stored in a folder called "uploads" in ~/Users/ron/uploads. The "../" means one directory above the current Rails root. If you want to go up two directories, it would be "../../" and so on.

But that only addresses hierarchical navigation. If you wanted to tell Attachment-Fu to store files in a hardcoded directory in your filesystem, you could give it a file path such as "~/Users/ron/APP_NAME/uploads", but keep in mind hardcoding in a file path this way is brittle and could be a pain point in the future should your file storage requirements change.

Hope that helps.